# Codeception, phantom JS - Is there somehow a way to read data from JS canvas on site?

Tags: phantomjs, codeception

I am making some acceptance codeception tests. After a click, I expect that some content will show up on my JS canvas (which is on page). This is not so easy, because that content is not html or css element. It is just one canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Codeception does not provide any methods to inspect JS canvas.
However it provides [executeJs](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#executeJS) method which can execute arbitrary javascript code.

I found [this article](https://qxf2.com/blog/selenium-html5-canvas-verify-what-was-drawn/) which explains how to retrieve image from canvas,
but it is up to you to figure out how to do image recognition.

Summary of the article:

> 1. Use the canvas element’s toDataURL() method to get an image of the canvas
> 2. Use Selenium’s execute_script() method to execute the toDataURL() JavaScript call
> 3. Compare the image generated with a baseline